# "in doing this" vs "by doing this"?

Tags: differences, american-english, nuance

> We hope that in doing this we have reduced at least some part of the frustration this issue has brought you.

I’m having uncertainties regarding the *in doing this* vs. *by doing this*.
I don’t want it to come off as if we’re only doing this for some reciprocal benefits. We genuinely did something to make up for a customer’s complaint and frustration.

What nuanced differences are there between ***in*** doing this and ***by*** doing this?

Comment: "How would you improve...?" is too broad. Proofreading is off-topic unless a specific concern is highlighted, which I guess you just about have. But haven't asked a clear question about your concern. Questions also get closed on here for lack of research; you should consider including in your question what research you have done into "in doing this" vs "by doing this". I suspect the answer as to what they mean is primarily opinion based, which is yet another close reason on this site. Overall your question doesn't look a good fit for the site.

Comment: All that said, I'm happy to try and be helpful to you, but get this question closed as not useful to anyone else. As a native British English speaker I would suggest that if you specifically did "this" in order to reduce the customer's frustration, then "by doing this" is the better fit, but "in doing this" is also acceptable wording.

Comment: Thank you Andy. I did the research and came up empty handed. The results I found on Google were totally off what I was searching for, and I am quite good at finding things on Google.

Comment: Sure, but *what* research? Did you check the words "in" and "by" in an online dictionary? Or did you google the phrases "in doing this" and "by doing this"? Did you google "difference between the prepositions *in* and *by*"? Or did you do something else? The point is that this website isn't somewhere to come to ask someone to look in a dictionary for you. And we don't know what you've tried in order to know where you've gone wrong if you don't tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. I've edited your question to explicitly pose the question I think you're asking. Please feel free to [edit] it further or to [roll back](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/408893/revisions) the changes.

Comment: “in doing this, X” means that X happens implicitly as part of doing the thing.  “by doing this, X” means that X is expected as a consequence of doing the thing.”  In your situation it seems ***by*** *doing this* is more appropriate.

Comment: @Jim I agree with the process/result differentiation, though I have the impression that the *in* version is slowly drifting towards the *by* version in some parts of Australian English. If you have a good reference, I'd invite you to upgrade your comment to an answer.

Comment: I have already asked the question... and answered it! This is a duplicate. See gerunds: difference between “on doing”, “by doing”, and “in doing”?

Answer (score 2):

**(1)** Both *by doing X* and *in doing X* form non-finite adjunct clauses of cause or reason. In the most general sense, they both mean 'as a consequence of doing X.' Consequently, there are many situations where both items, *be* and *in*, sound acceptable.

> (1) [**By / In refusing** to ratify the Kyoto Protocol on global
>       warming], the administration may have set the stage for
>       environmental catastrophe.

```
   (= As a consequence of refusing to ratify the Kyoto Protocol)
```

**(2)** However, the meaning of *by doing X* is wider, less restricted than the meaning of *in doing X*. When *in doing X* is acceptable, *by doing X* is generally also acceptable. The inverse is not true. There are specific cases where *by doing X* is fine, but *in doing X* is not.

Specifically, *by doing X* can not only denote any general reason (paraphrase: 'as a consequence of doing X') but is **also** used exclusively for direct causes - the action "doing X" is interpreted as an inherent, immediate cause, or typically the means, of a consequence. The action is a means to an end. The consequence is often brought about by the process of the action itself. (paraphrase for *by doing X* - 'as a DIRECT consequence of doing X').

> (2a) [**By** cheating on his exams], he improved his grades.
>
> (2b) ?* [**In cheating** on his exams], he improved his grades.

```
(= Here, "in" is odd because cheating is the direct cause, the means, the actual activity itself that leads to improved grades.)
```

In contrast, *in doing X* is **only** used to express indirect causes - the action "doing X" can always be potentially interpreted as the beginning of a causal chain with intermediate steps between the cause and its consequence. A process that follows from the action, not the action itself, is the cause. The consequence is often a side effect of the action (paraphrase for *in doing X* - 'as an INDIRECT consequence of doing X').

> (3a) [**In writing** a public internet post], he opened himself up to ridicule.
>
> (also acceptable: (3b) [**By writing** a public internet post], he opened himself up to ridicule.)

```
(= Writing is an indirect cause of ridicule. It's not the act of writing itself, but people reading the post, finding it silly, commenting on it etc., that causes the ridicule)
```

> (4a) [**In marrying** him], she would satisfy her mother.
>
> (also acceptable:  (4b) [**By marrying** him], she would satisfy her mother.)

```
(= Not the marriage itself satisfies her mother, but the indirect consequences, being with a certain kind of man, his money, virtues etc.)
```

> (5a) The government banned tobacco advertising and, [**in doing so**], contributed greatly to the nation's health.
>
> (also acceptable: (5b) The government banned tobacco advertising and, [**by doing so**], contributed greatly to the nation's health.)

```
( = Not the ban itself, but indirect consequences, fewer people being exposed to tobacco ads etc., contribted to the nation's health)
```

**(2a)** It follows that, where only *by* and not *in* is acceptable, the non-finite clause can often be praphrased as *by means of doing X*. After all, one common type of a direct cause is a means.

> (6a) the vulva is protruded [**by (means of) lifting up** the hips high]
>
> (6b) ?* the vulva is protruded [**in lifting up** the hips high]

```
(= Lifting up the hips high is the direct cause of, the means to achieve, protraction of the vulva)
```

> (7a) [**By (means of) practising** ten hours a day], you will become an expert.
>
> (7b) ?* [**In practising** ten hours a day], you will become an expert.

```
(= The very act of practising itself will cause expertise, which makes "in" sound unnatural. (7b) could only be interpreted with the acquired expertise as an indirect, accidental or even undesired consequence of practising.)
```

**(2b)** As another consequence, *by doing X* often has the connotation of intention, deliberate causation. *Thus, by doing X* is often interpreted as 'because I (deliberately) did X.' Since *in doing X* cannot signify direct causation, the expression is bizarre in cases of intended consequences.

> (8a) [**By pulling** out his gun], he (deliberately) wanted to scare the cashier.
>
> (8b) ?* [**In pulling** out his gun], he (deliberately) wanted to scare the cashier.

```
(= Pulling a gun was intended to cause fear, so it's a direct consequence, a means. Hence, "in" is not acceptable here.)
```

**(2c)** A final consequence of the suggested semantic difference is that *in doing X* is often preferred where the consequence is unintentional, accidental, not beneficial. That's because the typical relation of *in doing X* is one of indirect consequences. (However, as always, *by* is also fine in these cases.)

> (9) [**In altering** the rat's genes for longevity], the scientists **accidentally also** changed its intelligence.
>
> (10) [**In refusing** to subscribe to one confession], I **unfortunately** received a lot of backlash from the religious communities.
>
> (11) [**In seeking** to recover the stolen horse], he **unintentionally** stole another.

```
(= The focus on accidental, hence indirected, consequences work well with the "in doing X" structure.)
```

**(3)** The expression *in doing X* has been in decline for the last few hundred years. There is a good chance that it might eventually drop out of use completely. The following charts from COHA and Google Ngram illustrate:

[image: Frequency per million words of "in V-ing" in COHA]
***Figure 1***: Frequency per million words of "in V-ing" in COHA

[image: Normalized frequency of "in V-ing" for five common verbs in Google n-grams]
***Figure 2***: Normalized frequency of "in V-ing" for five common verbs in Google Ngram

**(3a)** The most likely reason for the decline is the assumption that *by doing X* is more general than *in doing X*. In virtually all cases where the latter is acceptable, the former would also be acceptable. The inverse is not true. It thus makes sense to drop the distinction between direct and indirect consequences and retain only the more general construction that is permissible in all senses - the general meaning 'as a consequence of X' associated with *by doing X*.

**(3b)** The decline in *in doing X* structure leads, as is typical in such situations, to a change in its associated meanings. Specifically, *in doing X* is beginning to sound archaic, old-fashioned, formal, literary, stilted, posh, and upper-class. You can easily use the expression to sound intelligent, in scientific papers, in parliamentary speeches, in serious situations etc., but it feels inadequate to sound colloquial and modern, when you chat with your friends, when you write a facebook post, in casual situations etc.

> (12a) Yeah, [**by inviting** this guy to my party], John really pissed me off!
>
> (12b) (inappropriate:) *#* Yeah, [**in inviting** this guy to my party], John really pissed me off!

```
(= The formal connotations of "in doing X" clash with the informal character of the sentence.)
```

> (13) The Government have been clear that, [**in leaving** the European Union], the UK will also leave its customs union.

```
(= The serious, political content of the sentence works well with the formal connotations of "in doing X")
```

**(4)** So, what does all of this mean for the initial example sentence?

- In principle both *in doing this* and *by doing this* are fine and the customer is unlikely to find either structure offensive.
- If the reference of "this" (*in doing this*) is the actual direct means, a resource, a gift, etc. that was given to the customer in order to reduce their frustration directly etc., then *by* is the best option. Can you paraphrase the sentence as *by means of doing this*?
- If the reference of "this" (*in doing this*) is supposed to express an indirect cause for the alleviation of the customer's troubles, perhaps an apology, store credit or bonus points that the customer may or may not use etc., then *in* is an elegant option. Are there intermediate steps between your action and the potential improvement in customer satisfaction?
- Do you want to stress your own effort? Do you want to focus on the energy you invested to get a direct response from the customer? Do you want to get credit for your action? Then go with *by*.
- Do you want to sound more apologetic? Do you want to show that it is up to the customer to accept your offer? Do you want to underline the indirect link between your action and the customer's power to forgive you? Then go with *in*.
- If you want to conduct your business relations on a formal, distant, serious, rigid level ("Dear Sir", "We look forward to hearing from you."), then *in doing X* is a great formulation.
- If you prefer a more colloquial, casual, informal, friendly way to talk to your customers ("Dear Bill", "Please let me know what you think about this"), then *in doing X* may come across as too snobbish, conceited or  distant.

Comment: This is a great first answer Richard. Welcome to EL&U!

Answer (score -1):

I'd certainly choose 'in doing this' here. This usage of 'in' is reasonably close in meaning to 'by' in the same context, but removes (at least partly) the implication that we have been so good as to do whatever it is. 'We hope that by doing this we ...' focuses rather more on 'we' than 'this'; there is more stress on the agency than with 'in', which is more suggestive of natural consequences.

'In' is also the more formal choice than 'by' here.

from [CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in):

> **in** preposition (CAUSE)
>
> ​ [ + -ing verb ] used to show when doing one thing is the cause of
>   another thing happening:
>
> In refusing (= because she refused) to work abroad, she missed an
>   excellent job opportunity.
>
> The government banned tobacco advertising and, in doing so (= because
>   of this), contributed greatly to the nation's health.